# How can you determine if the OpenNTF Ext Lib is installed and what version?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I know I can find the version of the Ext Lib with this code:

var v = com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getExtLibVersion();
return "XPages ExtLib version: "+v

But, that will not necessarily tell me if the Ext Lib installed is the IBM version or the OpenNTF version (with the LibX library). In particular, I am trying to figure out if the Extension Library has the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library support via code.

Any ideas on how to find out via code if a certain library is installed on a system?

Howard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate a class or call a static method from this package com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational inside a **try-catch-block**. If it throws an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` then you know this package is not installed.

Combine it with getExtLibVersion(); to be sure it is the version you need **if** class was found.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. In SSJS it throws 'com' not found but that is good enough to tell me they don't have the right support.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using code, you can check for a specific library using the following server console command:

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
```

The server will then respond with a list of library that matches the search term.

You can be more specific if you want to check for the relational library:

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational
```

If the library is installed, the server will list the library.

Comment: Thanks, I need a code solution...we distribute a database and it will be used on the Designer client, no console.